# launchd uses UDP port 69. Why?

Tags: launchd

Why and what for `launchd` listens on TFTP port 69?
How to prevent?

```
$ sudo lsof -nP -i:69
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd   1 root   23u  IPv6 0x55f5dbd8d897c847      0t0  UDP *:69
launchd   1 root   57u  IPv4 0x55f5dbd8d897e687      0t0  UDP *:69
launchd   1 root   59u  IPv6 0x55f5dbd8d897c847      0t0  UDP *:69
launchd   1 root   60u  IPv4 0x55f5dbd8d897e687      0t0  UDP *:69
```

I think this is a root problem why `tftpd` cannot listen on port 69 – port is already in use – and exits with status 1.

Comment: I voted to close this question as being a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/380235/46401 where you ask the exact same question in the update

Comment: No. This does not say how to start tftpd.

Comment: Could say duplicate. This Q is simpler and I belive has better chance s to be answered

Comment: I did say duplicate. The default “does this answer your question” comment was generated by the system after I voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate by meaning but by the goal could be.

Comment: Please keep updating your original question based on feedback you receive in comments there.

Comment: I'll convert this comment to an answer if the question is reopened: "If you're not used to launchd or similar programs on Unix-systems, it might seem counterintuitive - but this is how things are supposed to work.

Basically launchd does not start the tftpd server program at boot or when you login. Instead it opens port 69 and waits for someone to actually contact the tftp service - only when it is actually going to be used by someone, launchd starts the tftpd server program and hands over the traffic to that program.

Therefore it is as intended that port 69 is in use by launchd."